# How do a make a TextBlock control that can be disabled in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm trying to make some `TextBlock` controls in a custom `UserControl` be grayed out when the parent control is disabled (i.e. `IsEnabled = false`). For Headers etc. of standard controls this happens automatically, however `TextBlock` controls stay black. I assume this is because they don't have an `IsEnabled` property.

I tried making another `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.DisableableTextBlock"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    IsEnabledChanged="UserControl_IsEnabledChanged">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EnabledColour" Color="{StaticResource TextFillColorPrimary}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledColour" Color="{StaticResource TextFillColorDisabled}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</UserControl>
```

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;


namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class DisableableTextBlock : UserControl
    {
        public DisableableTextBlock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(DisableableTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(""));


        private void UserControl_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock.Foreground = Resources[IsEnabled ? "EnabledColour" : "DisabledColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

Which aimed to change the colour of the text when the control was disabled. However, the `IsEnabledChanged` event is not fired when the parent control is enabled or disabled. This doesn't seem to match [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.control.isenabledchanged?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1).

What am I missing? Is there a better way to 'disable' a `TextBlock` control when the parent is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsEnabledChanged` will be fired when you change it. You are setting the default value but you're not changing it.

So, you'll need to add something like this.

```cs
private void DisableableTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock.Foreground = Resources[IsEnabled ? "EnabledColour" : "DisabledColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
}
```